# How to draw the product topology diagram for $R^3$?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

How to draw the product topology diagram for $R^3$? How to draw this figure?

> [image]

Comment: With use of `tikz-cd` this should not be so difficult ... What you try so far?

Comment: There is also `xy` package :-))) used very rarely but it gives the same results even if it's a bit complicated.

Comment: xy is not as good as tikz-cd.Try drawing monomorphisms or inclusions and you will see that the spacing is not right

Comment: [for posterity] Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a small variation [of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529380/194703). One thing that requires a bit attention is the left-aligned column, which one gets with

```
/tikz/column 2/.style={nodes={align=left,text width={width("$\realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR$")}}}
```

Code (with two different double-stroke R's)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand{\realR}{\mathds{R}}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em,column sep=2.5em,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={nodes={align=left,text width={width("$\realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR$")}}}]
 & \realR & \\
 \mathcal{W} \arrow[ur,out=80,in=180,"g_1"] \arrow[dr,out=-80,in=180,"g_2"]
 \arrow[rr,out=-90,in=-110,"g_3",overlay] \arrow[r,dashed,"g"] 
 & \realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR \arrow[r,"Pr_3"]
 & \realR\\
 & \realR & \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
Or with another double-stroke R\renewcommand{\realR}{\mathbb{R}}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em,column sep=2.5em,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={nodes={align=left,text width={width("$\realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR$")}}}]
 & \realR & \\
 \mathcal{W} \arrow[ur,out=80,in=180,"g_1"] \arrow[dr,out=-80,in=180,"g_2"]
 \arrow[rr,out=-90,in=-110,"g_3",overlay] \arrow[r,dashed,"g"] 
 & \realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR \arrow[r,"Pr_3"]
 & \realR\\
 & \realR & \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: a supplement to Zarko's answer, in which the shift of the arrows gets computed from the `inner sep`, `outer sep` and the width of the real R. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand{\realR}{\mathds{R}}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em,column sep=2.5em,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={nodes={align=left,text width={width("$\realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR$")}}}]
 & \realR & \\
 \mathcal{W} \arrow[ur,out=80,in=180,"g_1"] \arrow[dr,out=-80,in=180,"g_2"]
 \arrow[rr,out=-90,in=-110,"g_3",overlay] \arrow[r,dashed,"g"] 
 & \realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR \arrow[r,"Pr_3"]
 % shift by half the width of the letter R + inner sep + outer sep (both equal 2pt)
 \arrow[u,start anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]north west},
    end anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]south west},"P_{p_1}"']
 \arrow[d,start anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]south west},
    end anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]north west},"P_{p_2}"]
 & \realR\\
 & \realR &\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
Or with another double-stroke R\renewcommand{\realR}{\mathbb{R}}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em,column sep=2.5em,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={nodes={align=left,text width={width("$\realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR$")}}}]
 & \realR & \\
 \mathcal{W} \arrow[ur,out=80,in=180,"g_1"] \arrow[dr,out=-80,in=180,"g_2"]
 \arrow[rr,out=-90,in=-110,"g_3",overlay] \arrow[r,dashed,"g"] 
 & \realR^3=\realR\times\realR\times\realR \arrow[r,"Pr_3"]
 % shift by half the width of the letter R + inner sep + outer sep (both equal 2pt)
 \arrow[u,start anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]north west},
    end anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]south west},"P_{p_1}"']
 \arrow[d,start anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]south west},
    end anchor={[xshift={width("$\realR$")/2+4pt}]north west},"P_{p_2}"]
 & \realR\\
 & \realR & \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As supplement to @Schrödinger's cat's answer. Added are vertical lines labeled `P_{r_1}` and `P_{r_2}` (which are shown in OP image but not in his answer) and made some small changes in image code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,
/tikz/column 2/.style={nodes={text width = {width("$\mathbb{R}^3= \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$")}}},
                    ]
    & \mathbb{R} 
      \ar[d,start anchor={[xshift=1em]south west},  
              end anchor={[xshift=1em]north west}, "P_{r_1}",<-] 
                        &               \\
\mathcal{W} \ar[ur,bend left,"g_1"] 
            \ar[r,dashed,"g"]
            \ar[dr,bend right,"g_2"]
            \ar[rr,bend right=90,"g_3",looseness=1.5] 
    & \mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} 
      \ar[r,"P_{r_3}"]  & \mathbb{R}    \\
    & \mathbb{R}
      \ar[u,start anchor={[xshift=1em]north west},
              end anchor={[xshift=1em]south west}, "P_{r_2}" ',<-]
                        &               \\
\end{tikzcd}
    \]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I will add the worst answer here because I don't like diagrams with many curved arrows or that `g_2` is so close to `g_3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& \mathbb{R}^3\\
W\ar{ru}{g_1}\ar[dashed]{r}[description]{g}\ar{rd}[swap]{g_2}\ar[out=270,in=270]{rrr}
& \mathbb{R}^3\ar{u}[swap]{pr_1}\ar{d}{pr_2}
&[-11mm] =\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\ar{r}{pr_3}
&\mathbb{R}\\
& \mathbb{R}
\end{tikzcd}


\end{document}
```

[image]